# Loading a https page in webview displays a blank page

Tags: android, webview

I need to display a secured website(https) in a webview. I have seen a few posts based on this problem and tried the solutions that were given. But nothing works for me..

It still displays white blank page.

Here is what i have done..

```
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view,
                SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            handler.proceed();
        }
    });
    webView.loadUrl(url);
```

can anyone help me what can I do to solve this ? do I need to add anything more ?

thanks,

Comment: Are you able to solve this issue, I have done what has beed suggested in blog but no luck. Can you post your solution.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is related to the level of the Android API you are using if i'm not mistaken. Until Android Froyo, there was to way to handle this in the API.

[This blog post](http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/android-webview-with-https-loadurl-shows-blankempty-page/) should help you solving your issue.